# WebView simply will NOT accept cookies

Tags: android, webview

```
 CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
 CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
 webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

Also tried using JUST:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

In every place imaginable, and YET im still not able to make it accept cookies? whats going on??

Comment: Try to move the webview initialization before the CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());  I don't know why i remember to this way. Also i guess you know that cookies are not being saved when you leave the Activity

Comment: @Alex nope, same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Tried several combinations of all the answers on stackoverflow, but WebView was simply ignoring cookies.

The solution that finally worked for me was to manually set the cookies using the CookieManager.

Initially, I was calling setCookie() on the CookieManager with an incorrect url, and my WebView was still ignoring cookies. You need to find the correct url, which is mostly likely the domain of the url you will call webView.loadUrl(url) with. If your webview performs several redirects, you might have to experiment with different domains to find the right one to set the cookies on. I had to set it to the domain that appears in one of the redirects, and not the domain of the url that I call webView.loadUrl(url) on.

```
final CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();

//Set the cookies one by one. You might extract these cookies from the headers like I did. 
//They were saved under the key "Set-Cookie". Or you might extract them from the http
//client like so httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies() depending on your implementation. 
// Assuming you have List<String> cookies to work with:
for (String cookie : cookies)
{                 
   cookieManager.setCookie("http://exampledomain.com", cookie.split(";")[0]);
}
cookieSyncManager.sync();
webView.loadUrl(url);
```